# Using Azure Function APP in Data Factory to run Python script

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am merging to CSV files from a blob storage and uploading it to a Data Lake storage(Gen 2). The code works in PyCharm and VS Code, but I would like to run it in an Azure Data Factory pipeline using a function app. I get this error if I try to run it in a pipeline: "Operation on target Azure Function1 failed: Call to provided Azure function 'name' failed with status-'Unauthorized' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - Unauthorized.'."

```
import azure.functions as func
import pandas as pd
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    STORAGEACCOUNTURL= 'https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/'
    STORAGEACCOUNTKEY= '****'
    LOCALFILENAME= ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']
    CONTAINERNAME= 'inputblob'

    file1 = pd.DataFrame()
    file2 = pd.DataFrame(])
    #download from blob

    blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)

    for i in LOCALFILENAME:
        with open(i, "wb") as my_blobs:
            blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(container=CONTAINERNAME, blob=i, snapshot=None)
            blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
            blob_data.readinto(my_blobs)
            if i == 'file1.csv':
                file1 = pd.read_csv(i)
            if i == 'file2.csv':
                file2 = pd.read_csv(i)

    # load

    # join the 2 dataframes into the final dataframe
    summary = pd.merge(left=file1, right=file2, on='key', how='inner')
        
    summary.to_csv(path_or_buf=r'path\summary.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')

    global service_client
            
    service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="https://storage.dfs.core.windows.net/", credential='****')
        
    file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="outputdatalake")

    directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("functionapp") 

    file_client = directory_client.create_file("merged.csv")
            
    local_file = open(r"path\summary.csv",'rb') 

    file_contents = local_file.read()

    file_client.upload_data(file_contents, overwrite=True) 

    return func.HttpResponse("This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
```

Comment: For invoking the azure function api, you need an API key. Have you checked if you have used the correct function API key to invoke the API? You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#authorization-keys to know about API keys. Also check if you can invoke this Azure function API from postman.

Comment: I have added an API to my function, but now I get this error: " Operation on target Azure Function1 failed: Call to provided Azure function 'name' failed with status-'InternalServerError' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - InternalServerError.'. "  @AnupamChand

Comment: Is your function getting invoked? Did you check on the application insights? It will show you the logs. If it is not getting invoked then you need to attach a pic your linked service settings to your question.

Comment: [Here is my linked service @AnupamChand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgQWG.png)

Comment: Did you check you app service application insight logs to see if your function is getting invoked at all? It is possible that your function is getting invoked but failing due to some reason.

Comment: I have checked it, but I could not find whether the function is invoked or not.

Comment: Have you tried firing a request to the API from postman to see if your function deployment is working fine on Azure? It is possible that the problem is now with your function and not with ADF.

Comment: Yeah the API is running fine. I have checked the logs and I get this error message: 
[Information]   Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.                        
 2021-11-09T11:52:22Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.beerfunction' (Failed, Id=2832dd08-ce5e-4bf8-8c98-d96f67e1f905, Duration=23ms)"

Comment: So this confirms my suspicion that the API is getting invoked but failing for some other reason . You will need to debug and check why it is failing. We cannot analyze this using just what you have provided so far. Was your requirements.txt updated? Was there any other errors in your application insight logs which tells you why the function failed?

Comment: Yes I updated the requirements.txt file. The debugger in VS Code runs until this message pops up "Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '****'". Then it runs infinitely without any other message. There are no errors popping up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce with python based http trigger and after first deployement faced the below error

```
Call to provided Azure function 'HttpTriggerT' failed with status-'Unauthorized' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - Unauthorized.'.
```

[image]

**Note:** Try to refresh and **restart** the Function App service after deployment or changes to it. This is know to solve few transient issues.

[image]

Ideally you can use function key (for particular single function) or master/host key (for all functions in the function app service) to allow access. Managed identity provides secure access to the entire function app

1. For using function key,

Navigate to your **function app > functions > your_function > Function Keys**

[image]

Copy the key and add in the functions linked service to authorize

[image]

2. For using Managed Identity

### Further I have made following changes to get it working.

**Navigate to your deployed function app, Settings > Identity > Turn on System assigned managed identity.**

[image]

**Add an identity provider. Settings > Authentication > Microsoft Identity**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Create Managed Identity for ADF:**

[image]

[image]

**Add credentials to ADF**

[image]

[image]

**Finally edit Azure functions linked service**

[image]

**Get the resource ID from the AAD App registered as identity provider**

[image]

[image]

### Test function call in pipeline

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I am not authorized to create a new app registration as an identity provider.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @KarthikBhyresh-MT ! Is there another way to make the function work without a managed  identity?

Comment: What is the exact error that you see now when calling the function activity from pipeline. I guess you used function keys already to by pass `HttpStatusCode - Unauthorized` error

Comment: ideally you can use function key (for particular single function) or master/host key (for all functions in the function app service) to allow access. Managed identity provides secure access to the entire function app

Comment: I get this error: "Operation on target Azure Function failed: Call to provided Azure function 'function' failed with status-'InternalServerError' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - InternalServerError.'." @KarthikBhyresh-MT

Comment: Oki this basically means an issue with your code, make sure you have the body parameter  or inputs are available for the function

Comment: Recheck all the dynamic inputs you had, storage account credentials, files are all in place. Debug locally save code you have deployed

Comment: is it POST method ? Do you have to pass something in the `Body`  while calling the function from pipeline. If not make sure its empty

Comment: If I debug the code locally, I don"t get any errors just the debugger says "Host lock lease acquired by instance ID" and I have to shut it down to stop the debugger. The function body for post should not be empty, but I"m not sure what to put there.

Comment: Are you following any documentation or blog to do this ? If the function is not expecting any input, just set `GET` API method in function activity settings in pipeline

Comment: I tried it but I get the same error with GET method as well with POST.

Comment: Should I use a different function trigger? This is my function.json file:`{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "main",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: Set "authLevel": "function" and try redeploy and restart app service

Comment: I still get the same error: "Operation on target Azure Function1 failed: Call to provided Azure function 'function' failed with status-'InternalServerError' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - InternalServerError.'."

Comment: Is it possible to create a function in ADF without a trigger? To just run my script, because I don't need a HTTP trigger.

Comment: Absolutely, see [Manually run a non HTTP-triggered function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http)

Comment: Yeah I know you can do it in Postman, but can I do it in a pipeline with an Azure function block?

Comment: Just use Web Activity instead of postman. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity

Comment: Form the URL as request location, explained in the earlier doc I shared

Comment: Also, Since initially your question was mainly related to error `HttpStatusCode - Unauthorized` , and I have shared in answer ways to authorize, could you consider and [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem 

Comment: For this non HTTP-triggered function query, you can post as new question, or first try the docs as I shared above